# Approaches to automatic Plug and Play Raspberry PI WebSockets

Tags: python, api, websocket, raspberry-pi

This question is more about advice on how to approach the best solution and possible frameworks to look at.

**Desired Result**

I am currently attempting to create a very basic plug and play raspberry-pi which can be controlled via an API to perform various tasks such as stream a webcam or turn an led on. The device should connect to anyway wifi and automatically be able to be controlled by the API.

**Current Problem**

The goal of the app is to create a very easy to use plug and play solution. However I am running to to problem when trying to create a WebSocket on the PI as I cannot seem to be able to access it from an external network. I have looked into automatic port forwarding solutions such as UPnP however all of the results are extremely old. I have also thought about creating the Python WebSocket on a cloud server and use the PI as the client to connect and pass data. Please correct me if I am wrong, however this method does not seem very scalable when there are 10s/100s/1000s of pi's connecting to the same socket.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.